# Issue with assigning a value to flash message within format.html hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I'm following the "Agile Web Development with Rails 4" tutorial and I've run into a slight problem while trying to assign a value to the flash hash which will create a flash message in the application beneath the navbar. When I run my test suite I get this error:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer
        app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:34:in `[]'
        app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in create'
        app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:32:in `create'
        test/controllers/line_items_controller_test.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <class:LineItemsControllerTest>'
        test/controllers/line_items_controller_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:LineItemsControllerTest>'
```

and this is the create action in the line_items_controller:

```
def create
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @line_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, :flash[success: 'Line item was successfully created.'] }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

and this is how the flash message will render in the application.This is from the application.html.erb layout file. It uses string interpolation to automatically change the bootstrap class according to the value that is placed with flash hash.

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
<%= content_tag :div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}" %>
```

I'm quite sure it's just a simple formatting issue (in the format.html line..) but I can't figure out how to fix it! All help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:flash[success: 'Line item was successfully created.']
```

The way you are trying to render the flash message above is wrong.

You should do this instead:

```
flash[:success] = 'Line item was successfully created.'
```

[See this](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) to know more about how to set a key's value in a Hash.

Replace:

```
format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, :flash[success: 'Line item was successfully created.'] }
```

with:

```
  format.html {
    flash[:success] = 'Line item was successfully created.'
    redirect_to @line_item.cart
  }
```

You can also use this:

```
format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, flash: { success: 'Line item was successfully created.' } }
```

Both of these should work and solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! that worked. However, in the interest of learning I'd like to know why yours works and mine doesn't. Is there a specific order I must follow when writing it? Perhaps you can point me to documentation. Thanks again for all your help

Comment: `:flash[success: 'Line item was successfully created.']` this part is wrong in your posted question and you are getting this error: `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into Integer`. You are not using the proper format of  hash to set a value to a key of the hash. This is correct: `flash[:success] = 'Line item was successfully created.'`, you are setting the value of `success` key in the `flash` hash. Hope it makes it clear!